# Unable to get though NotSerializableException in jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline job that runs the following groovy script but throws the following exception as soon as jenkins sees the line with sh command. I can't seem to get away with this exception even after annotating the method with @NonCPS.
What am I missing?

```
node {
    stage('Kill Long Running jobs') {
        try {
            def longRunningJobs = getLongRunningJobs()
            if (longRunningJobs.size() > 0) {
                def metricData = killAndGetMetricData(longRunningJobs)
                if (metricData.size() > 0) {
                    def payload = metricData.join('\n')
                    sh("curl -X POST ${ENDPOINT} --data-binary ${payload}")
                }
            } else {
                echo 'No long running jobs'
            }
        } catch (err) {
            throw err
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def getLongRunningJobs() {
    def timeInMillis = 24*3600*1000
    def rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
    return Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).findAll { Job job ->
        job.isBuilding()
    }.collect { Job job ->
        //find all matching items and return a list but if null then return an empty list
        job.builds.findAll { Run run ->
            run.isBuilding() && ((rightNow.getTimeInMillis() - run.getStartTimeInMillis()) > timeInMillis)
        } ?: []
    }.sum()
}
```

Error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5dc513b2
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@788991c6
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@76c7fb80
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@41b11dd6
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@4a0dec81
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@21e5f4ba
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.TryBlockEnv@69fbc75f
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@430907d9
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@779bb867
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@e363a3
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@29a42aee
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@23c20513
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@23c20513
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't leak heavy internal Jenkins objects like "Job" into the CPS part of your pipeline. Since Jenkins' pipeline job type needs to be able to suspend & resume pipelines at any time, all objects in pipeline need to be serializable - most internal Jenkins objects are not designed with that in mind.

If you really need to work with Jenkins-internal objects in pipeline, wrap all that into `@NonCPS` methods. As a rule of thumb: Only use "simple" objects like String or List in pipeline CPS code. For your code above I would suggest to:

- Either return a list of Strings (job names?) from `getLongRunningJobs()` and modify `killAndGetMetricData()` to take a list of strings
- Or (probably easier) refactor your code to combine both methods and only return a list of strings (or even just the payload string)

See https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/ for more technical details